# Need help MySQL Optimizations mysqltuner issues

Tags: mysql, apache, mysqltuner

I'm using MySQLTuner.pl to optimize my site/srever.... 
though I'm not entirely sure how to resolve some of these issues and am wondering if someone can help me out.

I have VPS with 4GB ram, THIS IS my.cnf settings:

```
[mysqld]    
expire_logs_days=14
sync_binlog=1

query_cache_limit=32M
query_cache_size=128M

slow_query_log=1
log_queries_not_using_indexes=0

thread_cache_size=50

max_allowed_packet=16M
max_connect_errors=1000000
max_connections=250
key_buffer_size=8M

open_files_limit=65535
tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=256M
table_definition_cache=2048
table_open_cache=2048
default_storage_engine=InnoDB

innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_log_files_in_group=2
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=40M
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=90
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=64M
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1152M
```

Here's the output of mysqltuner:

```
-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 2d 8h 36m 40s (7M q [34.897 qps], 504K conn, TX: 41B, RX: 735M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 68% / 32%
[--] Total buffers: 2.0G global + 2.8M per thread (200 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 2.5G (63% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (30K/7M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 20% (40/200)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/7.8M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 99.9% (1M cached / 1K reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 29.3% (1M cached / 4M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 11573
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (3K temp sorts / 999K sorts)
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 48% (54K on disk / 112K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (40 created / 504K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 33% (499 open / 1K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (380/65K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (4M immediate / 4M locks)
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 1.1G/1001.0M
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0
-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Increasing the query_cache size over 128M may reduce performance
    Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (> 512M) [see warning above]
```

1. Is there anything I also can improve for better performance?
2. how to fix this:

Temporary tables created on disk: 48%

Query cache prunes per day: 11573

Query cache efficiency: 29.3%

### **UPDATE:**

I would be happy if you can give their opinions on the setting in my.cnf
(Because I'm not an expert and the setting is what I saw in other systems on the internet, maybe some incorrect)

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it come to optimization, I believe in "don't fix if it isn't broke". that said heres an excellent post regarding temp tables on disk

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17677/why-is-mysql-is-creating-so-many-temporary-tables-on-disk

if you are not sure what to do with those settings then it is a huge sign saying "Do not touch". Maybe you should change your question a bit, tell everyone WHY would you want to optimize the DB. Is it because something ran extremly slow? Is it because the DB is taking up too much resource of the server? Optimization without a specific goal is quite dangerous, optimization means tweaking a system in a way that best suits the way you use it, which implies a  lot of the time you are trading the preformance in some other area that you don't need, which in your case we have no idea what you don't need.

Comment: Yes. Tuning scripts in general are horrible, because they make blind recommendations and encourage tweaking of things that can seem like a good idea, but have negative consequences.  The solution to many, many performance issues is learning about query plans and the optimizer, and writing better queries... not "tuning."

Comment: couldn't agree more. I personally believe 95% of the time the actual performance bottleneck will be on the query itself. That said, there are usually a lot of reasons for one to attempt optimization, a lot of them might not be even optimization related, such as learning the engine/SQL via optimization or simply tweaking the stats so that one could show to their boss that "the performance has gone up 53.21% !" without actually optimizing anything XD

Comment: I would be happy if you can give their opinions on the setting in my.cnf, Because I'm not an expert and the setting is what I saw in other systems on the internet, maybe some incorrect. thank you all

Comment: my comment is a bit too long for comment section, I've put it in my answer.